# Powershell - get content from user profiles

Tags: powershell, foreach

new to Powershell and scripting, so here it goes.  I'm trying to go through a list of pc's to pull out any Java exception sites (eventually I will query AD for all my workstations).  The exception.sites file is located in each user profile \AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security folder. I'm not sure why I'm only pulling the sites from my workstation though.

```
$comps = Get-Content \\server1\users\james\test\comps.txt
$addPath = "\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security"
$userprofiles = Get-WmiObject win32_userprofile -filter "LocalPath Like '%\\Users\\%'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Localpath | foreach {$_ + $addpath}
foreach ($pc in $comps)
    {foreach ($profile in $userprofiles)
        {if ((test-path "$profile\exception.sites") -ne $false)
        {get-content -path "$profile\exception.sites" | Out-File \\server2\packages\java\siteexceptions\SiteExceptions.txt -Append
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make a couple of adjustments to the code.

Get-WmiObject has a `-computername` parameter which will make it run on a remote computer. Also you will need to move the WMi query inside the computer loop so that the query is run once on each computer that you are iterating.

Note: Since the destination points to a location within another user's profile, you will need administrator privileges to be able to traverse the protected path.

```
foreach ($pc in $comps)
{

$userprofiles = Get-WmiObject win32_userprofile -filter "LocalPath Like '%\\Users\\%'" -ComputerName $pc

foreach ($profile in $userprofiles)
{
    $drive = (Split-Path -Path $profile.localpath -Qualifier) -replace ':','$'
    $Remotepath =  "\\$pc\$drive" + (Split-Path -Path $profile.localpath -NoQualifier) + $addPath + '\exception.sites'
    if (test-path $Remotepath)
    {
        get-content -path $Remotepath | Out-File \\server2\packages\java\siteexceptions\SiteExceptions.txt -Append

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @kiran. I had to add some of the variables back to the code to get it running, but I'm still having the same issue. To test, I only put one remote workstation in the comp.txt and put a custom url in the exception.sites file. When I run the script, it's still pulling from my local exception.sites. Did I break it with the Select-Object -ExpandProperty Localpath | foreach {$_ + $addpath}?

Comment: `$comps = Get-Content \\server1\users\james\test\comps.txt 
$addPath = "\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security"   
foreach ($pc in $comps)
{

$userprofiles = Get-WmiObject win32_userprofile -filter "LocalPath Like '%\\Users\\%'"  -computername $pc | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Localpath | foreach {$_ + $addpath}

foreach ($profile in $userprofiles)
    {if ((test-path "$profile\exception.sites") -ne $false)
        {get-content -path "$profile\exception.sites" | Out-File \\server2\packages\java\siteexceptions\SiteExceptions.txt -Append
        }
        }
}
`

Comment: ok i see the issue...the localpath points to the localpath on the remote server so when checking for this remote path you would have to use the UNC syntax (\\servername)...check the modified answer.

Comment: Thanks again @Kiran, worked like a charm!  I also added a line to take the output and give only unique entries.  I'll paste the code below for anyone who needs it.

Comment: `$comps = Get-Content \\server1\users\james\test\comps.txt 
$addPath = "\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\security" 
foreach ($pc in $comps)
{

$userprofiles = Get-WmiObject win32_userprofile -filter "LocalPath Like '%\\Users\\%'" -ComputerName $pc
`

Comment: `foreach ($profile in $userprofiles)
{
    $drive = (Split-Path -Path $profile.localpath -Qualifier) -replace ':','$'
    $Remotepath =  "\\$pc\$drive" + (Split-Path -Path $profile.localpath -NoQualifier) + $addPath + '\exception.sites'
    if (test-path $Remotepath)
    {
        get-content -path $Remotepath | Out-File \\server2\packages\java\siteexceptions\SiteExceptions.txt -Append

    }
}
}
Get-Content \\server2\packages\java\siteexceptions\SiteExceptions.txt | Sort-Object | Get-Unique | Out-File \\server2\packages\java\siteexceptions\ExceptionsFinal.txt
`